# Find the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi\sqrt{1+n^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

Determine the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi\sqrt{1+n^2}).$$

**My Approach:** I have myself solved the problem over $n\in\mathbb N$, but do not have any clue on how to solve it over $n\in\mathbb R$. My solution for $n\in\mathbb N$ is as follows but my question is is the following problem even solvable over $n\in\mathbb R$? Anyways, here is my solution for $n\in\mathbb N$.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi\sqrt{1+n^2})&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi\sqrt{1+n^2}-2n\pi)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi(\sqrt{1+n^2}-n))\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(2\pi\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+n}\right)\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+n}\right)}{\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+n}}\right)\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\cdot\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+n} \right)\\
&=\pi
,\end{align*}
which completes the proof when $n\in\mathbb N$. But the problem is when I used that $-2n\pi$, I used the fact that $n\in\mathbb N$, and nowhere it is told what $n$ is which is why I doubt if this problem is solvable.

Thank you.

Comment: It diverges for $n\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Does the limit even exist over the reals?  Try starting there first. sin() is bounded and oscillating but n grows without bound...

Comment: I would never use the letter $n$ to denote a non-integer number... I would say that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is implicit here.

Comment: A necessary condition for the existence of the finite  limit is $\lim_n\sin ( 2\pi\sqrt{ n^2+1})=0.$ Clearly it does  hold if $ n\to\infty$ over the real numbers. A necessary condition for the existence of the improper limit is $\sin(2\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})\neq 0$ for large $n.$ Clearly it does not hold for real $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Wow, I just realized how dumb I am. I could've just explicitly chosen some $n\in\mathbb R$ (if the problem were intended for $\mathbb R$ so that the $\sin(\cdots)$ gave me a finite value $\not=0$ and then upon multiplying with $n$, it would clearly diverge as $n$ diverges. Thanks everyone! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sequences
$$
x_n = \sqrt{n^2 - 1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_n = \sqrt{\left( n + \tfrac{1}{4} \right)^2 - 1}.
$$
For $f(x) = x \sin(2 \pi \sqrt{1 + x^2})$, one has
$$
f(x_n) = x_n \sin(2 \pi n) = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(y_n) = y_n \sin \left( 2 \pi n + \tfrac{\pi}{2} \right) = y_n \to \infty \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$
Thus $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can set $\sqrt{1+n^2}=m+1/4$ where the $m$ are integers that tend to infinity.  If real $n$ follows this path then the expression clearly diverges.

Answer (score -1):

Trigonometric functions are bounded, in this case: $-1 \leq\sin([...])\leq1$ and $n$ is not bounded

**Tip**: sine function goes to infinity slower or faster than $n$?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that tip. The sine function is bounded like you said, so how could it go to infinity?